# Why does GCC do not use builtins in strict mode?

Tags: optimization, gcc

GCC [disables lots of builtins](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) when running in strict mode `-std=c...`.

> Outside strict ISO C mode (-ansi, -std=c90, -std=c99 or -std=c11), the
>   functions _exit, alloca, bcmp, bzero ... stpcpy, ... may be handled as
>   built-in functions. All these functions have corresponding versions
>   prefixed with _*builtin*, which may be used even in strict C90 mode.

Is there any reason for that ? Are the builtins not conformant ? Or is this because the standard says that when you call `memcpy` it should actually call it and that i can't be optimized out ?

I feel like my code could then definitely run faster if i recompiled it using `-std=gnu*` because it would enable some more [optimizations](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#C-Dialect-Options)

> GCC normally generates special code to handle certain built-in
>   functions more efficiently; for instance, calls to alloca may become
>   single instructions which adjust the stack directly, and calls to
>   memcpy may become inline copy loops

Answer (score 5, accepted):

None of `_exit`, `alloca`, `bcmp`, `bzero`, `stpcpy` or any of the other functions in that list are defined in the C standard, so they should not be defined by a conforming C compiler; these names must be available to the user for their own identifiers.

Note that many other built-ins are still enabled in strict ISO mode. E.g., `memcpy` is "recognized as [a] built-in [function] unless `-fno-builtin` is specified"

Comment: ouch, you're right. i think i've read to quickly the doc and mixed up the function lists. but your explanation stands anyway. thanks.